# Centos 6.3 is not booting

Tags: linux

I just used the command:

```
yum remove autofs bluez-utils bluez-gnome bluez-libs cups iptables iptables-ipv6 irda-utils pcsc-lite pcsc-lite-libs spamassassin squid sendmail
```

and now my CentOS sticks at the loading screen. I am new to linux and am having trouble figuring out what my next step is. I have tried hitting 'i' when the system is booting for Interactive mode.

Comment: Time to find out if your backups work.  Seriously though, what in tarnation gave you the idea to do that? If you don't know what each of those things does, it's a good idea to find out before nuking your box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've trashed your system beyond repair, and will most likely need to reinstall from scratch.

Next time, inspect the list of packages very carefully when using `yum remove` as it very often can and will remove critical system packages.

Comment: haha, yeah i was trying to remove unneeded programs from my computer while following a guide, and figured that it was trashed when it didn't boot. Live and learn. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Beginning with 6.3, CentOS has a specially built "minimal" ISO image which prompts for almost nothing and installs a minimal system. You may find this a better starting point for your project.